# Prompting and Acting on Response in vim

Tags: vim

I have vim set up to save empty files automatically when I create one:

```
 autocmd BufNewFile * :write
```

And, I have the fugitive plugin for git installed.  In fugitive :Gwrite will add the current file to git if necessary, and stage the changes to be committed.

What I would like to be able to do, is what PHP Storm does.  If I add a file, it prompts me and asks me if I want to add it to git as well.  So, ideally, I would like to type :edit some_new_filename, have it create the buffer, save the file, and then prompt if I want to add it to git.  If I say yes, it should add it, and if I say no, it should not.

I have not seen any examples of prompts and responses in vim; so I honestly don't even know if it's possible.  Is it, and if so, will you please help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `confirm` function to prompt the user for an answer:

```
function! PromptToAddTheFileToGit(filename)
    if(confirm("Add ".a:filename." to git","&Yes\n&no")==1)
        "Some code to add the file to git
    end
endfunction
```

Then you call that function

Comment: Thank you.  It took quite some time to work out the 'some code to add the file to git' but after reading a couple of git plugins, I finally figured it out.